# Is there a way to show video using video tag in a HTML page with XHTML Mobile Profile?

Tags: html, video, mobile, dtd

I have an html with following DTD declaration.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
```

I want to use video inside this page. Is there any workaround? I cannot change `DOCTYPE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that DTD definitely includes the Embedded Object Module so you should be able to include an `<object>` tag. I can't promise you that it will work in your environment (especially given the limited processing environment of a mobile device) but something like:

```
<object data="video.avi" type="video/avi" />
```

is certainly valid under that DTD.